# how to change the element stacking order in the table element?

Tags: html, css, html-table, z-index

Like the demo below, The first colunm covers the first row in the table defaultly, how to change it to the first row covers the first colunm?

I try to use `z-index`, but the `<table> <thead> <tbody> <tr>` elements can't be setted to `position: relative;`, is there anyway to do this?

```css
thead {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  z-index: 10;
}

tbody>tr>td {
  background-color: grey;
}

tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>HEAD</td>
      <td>NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr I just want to make the table with a frozen colunm and row(sticking the `first colunm` and the `first row`, the first row need to cover the first colunm when scrolling.The right stacking order should be `first row` > `first colunm` > `other cell`.

Answer (score 1):

use   `position: relative;` and 
    `z-index: -1;` to the first

```css
thead {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  z-index: 10;
}

tbody>tr>td {
  background-color: grey;
}


tbody>tr>td:first-child {
background-color: orange;
transform: translateX(10px);
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>HEAD</td>
      <td>NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that what do you mean?

Comment: I guess setting `z-index:-1` is not the good option all the time

Comment: At the same time -1 will takes the element under the `body`. You can use some positive values up and down instead of negative values.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sghujrqe/4/ the first colunm will be covered by other colunms.

Comment: I find you answer could do the job, but this snippet want to show that `the first colunm will be covered by other colunms.` This is actually a wrong way. The right stacking order should be `first row` > `first colunm` > `other cell`.

Comment: but how can you guarantee the stacking order is right in this snippet? (`first row` > `first colunm` > `other cell`)

Comment: can you explain??

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. removed the `transform: translateY(20px);` from `thead` and added `transform: translateX(10px)` added to the `thead`

```css
thead {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateX(10px);
  z-index: 10;
}

tbody>tr>td {
  background-color: grey;
}

tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>HEAD</td>
      <td>NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no, I just want to make the table with a frozen colunm and row, the first row need to cover the first colunm when scrolling. so `transform: translateY(20px);` is a right thing and do not need to modify.

Comment: Just explain me one thing. You have two columns in 1st row, Do you want to stick the both columns in the top when scrolling? Or do you want to stick only one column when you scroll

Comment: Stick Both the `first colunm` and the `first row`.

Comment: With your HTML DOM it's hard to achieve. You need to change your DOM like the header row, sidebar column and the table content. Else your data's will be overlapped and it will look like a mess